# What tool is used to generate Android's API XML files?

Tags: android

The Android git tree provides a set of XML files describing the public API, e.g. [base.git/api](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=api;h=4b81e932f2e6a83bf022a9918b143e732b15fd2c;hb=HEAD), e.g. [base.git/api/7.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=api/7.xml;h=83d2bc74d18656bc99bb133a27d0cf6859193d57;hb=HEAD) (which contains the public API for Android 2.1).

Does anybody know how this file is generated?  I would imagine that it uses some tool to process the android.jar file into an XML file (likely using `java.lang.reflect`).

I ask principally because I need to process this file, and the file contains many deficiencies, e.g. there are types which implement the `java.util.List` interface, but `java.util.List` isn't defined in the file, and generic information is missing from the file (e.g. `java.util.Vector` is generic, but there isn't any way to tell that from the XML file).

Answer (score 1):

[doclava](http://doclava.googlecode.com) can generate the API XML file using the following parameters

```
-xmlapi output_file.xml
```

[link to same question about DroidDoc](http://osdir.com/ml/android-platform/2009-07/msg00403.html) and I think DroidDoc is either a component of doclava or doclava is the DroidDoc replacement.

Answer (score 0):

The tool is called `apicheck`, you can find it in `/out/host/linux-x86/bin/apicheck` for example

Comment: Thank you!  src is at: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/build.git;a=tree;f=tools/apicheck;h=14ccf7030bd01a33980d83f22d55f3c96a4ddaef;hb=HEAD

Comment: Actually, that doesn't appear to be it. Based on ApiCheck.java, it accepts two XML files as parameters, so I'm still not sure how the XML is generated. :-/